# Adding a horizonal line to separate band of bars in geom_col in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I guess my question is very simple for someone who knows ggplot very well but I spent a lot of time trying different ways. I want to draw a horizontal line that pass-through y axis to separate each band of the bars produced using `geom_col`. For example, I want to draw a horizontal line that separate bars of meat from maize. Here is my code, example data and the design of the figure I want to produce.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

#  sample data 
Food = c("meat", "meat", "meat", "meat", "wheat","wheat","wheat", "wheat", "maize","maize","maize","maize")
Subgroup = c("Male", "Female", "Urban", "Rural", "Male",  "Female", "Urban", "Rural",  "Male",  "Female","Urban", "Rural")
mean = c(8.66, 10.45,  9.88,  7.32, 21.04, 19.65, 20.26, 20.87, 51.06 , 44.51,  47.60, 48.40)
df <- data.frame(Food, Subgroup,  mean)

#Color code
colorPanel = c('#083c5d','#2d004b','#106d8e','#7d103d')

# Plot
Plot_FBGDS <-  ggplot(df, aes(x = Food, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(-0.9), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  coord_flip() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, using `geom_vline` with manually specified `xintercept`.

```
# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = Food, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(-0.9), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5)) + 
  coord_flip() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ")
```

Note that `geom_vline` typically produces a vertical line, but since you have `coord_flip` it becomes horizontal. Without the `coord_flip`, you would use `geom_hline` and set the `yintercept` parameter instead.

Also, if I may suggest an alternative way to visualize this using `facet_wrap` instead, I would say the option below looks a lot better and you can style the facets using the `strip_` properties in `plot_theme`

```
# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = Subgroup, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(-0.9), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  coord_flip() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  facet_wrap(~Food, ncol=1)
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

Comment: I'd not use coord_flip, but switch the x and y aesthetic, this makes everything much more intuitive, and you can use geom_hline. You will then need scale_x_continuous instead, of course. Also, I'd suggest to remove the stat = "identity" and use labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) instead.

Comment: I have tried geom_vline. The problem with geom_vline is  that the line doesn’t cross the axis. But I want the horizonal lines to cross the x axis and separate the labels too. Is there a way to extend the horizontal lines beyond the x axis.

Comment: Totally agree with tjebo. And I don't think so because the geom is restricted to the plot area, you would probably have to do something funky with grobs to get that to work. Or just use `facet_wrap` which is the right tool for this...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to build off [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685889/9664796) already posted here from @geoff.  OP requested lines that extend beyond the plot area into the axis label.  It's true that normally geoms are restricted to the panel area alone, but that's only by default.  For any of the `coord_*()` functions, you can change the default clipping from "on" to "off" via `clip="off"`.

For `geom_vline()` and `geom_hline()`, these seem to be automatically clipped to the panel area (more on that below), but for just about all other geoms, you can extend beyond the plot area.  We can use this to our advantage in using `geom_segment()` and specifying the lines.

In this example, I'm going to need to create a `linesdata` data frame outside of the plot to make drawing the lines a bit easier (and reference that dataset in `geom_segment()`).  We also need to change `clip="off"` within `coord_flip()`, and finally, I had to adjust the value for the staring value of the line (`y` here because we flip the axis) to be some negative value to get below the axis.

```
linesdata <- data.frame(
  xvals = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
  Subgroup=NA   # required because it complains for fill, which I cannot specify again for geom_segment.
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Food, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(-0.9), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  coord_flip(clip="off") + 
  geom_segment(
    data=linesdata, y=-5, yend=Inf,
    aes(x=xvals, xend=xvals)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ")
```

[image]

Note that I had to include `Subgroup` as a column in the `linesdata` data frame.  The way to avoid having to do this would be to specify the `fill=` aesthetic inside `geom_col` instead of globally... but it works this way too.

#### The reason why geom_hline and vline always clip

Interestingly, you'll note that even though `yend=Inf`, the line *does not extend beyond the panel area* in the positive direction!  I had no idea this works this way, but It seems `Inf` is specially designed to clip to the panel area no matter what.  I'm pretty sure that `geom_vline()` and `geom_hline()` are using values of `Inf` and `-Inf` under the hood.  If I change the value to `y=-Inf` inside `geom_segment()` you can see it doesn't extend the same way as specifying a number:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Food, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(-0.9), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  coord_flip(clip="off") + 
  geom_segment(
    data=linesdata, y=-Inf, yend=Inf,
    aes(x=xvals, xend=xvals)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ")
```

[image]

The only problem here is that you have to play around a bit to find the right value for the starting y value via trial and error.  I found -5 did the trick pretty well.

Comment: TIL that you could do this. Appreciate you expanding!